# Reference Textarea W/ Input

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking to build a simple webpage that can check to see if a string contains certain information. I'm taking a summer course in Java and wanted to give Javascript a try. Maybe a bad idea?

I want the user to enter information - name, phone number, and a couple other options in a form. Then I want the user to enter more information in the text area. The text area will reference the input data and if there is a match it will alert the user.

I have limited javascript experience, but I've been able to manipulate user input with javascript in the past.

Not sure what my problem here is. Any tips (especially regarding style and logic) are greatly appreciated! PS - I'm using Bootstrap if that matters...

Thanks in advance :)

HTML

```
       <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-6">
         <form>
          <input type="text" id="Name" placeholder="Name" style="width:100%"><br /><br />
          <input type="text" id="Number" placeholder="Number" style="width:100%"><br /><br />
          <input type="text" id="Next" placeholder="Something Else" style="width:100%"><br /><br />
          <input type="text" id="WhatEver" placeholder="Something Else" style="width:100%"><br /><br />
         </form>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">

          <textarea id="LongText" placeholder="Enter Info" style="width:100%; height:250px">  
          </textarea> <br />

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="tSubmit" value="Submit" onclick="GetInput();Check();">
      </div>


        <div class="col-md-12">
         <h1>Output</h1>
            <div id="tOutPut" style="color:red;"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

JS

```
   GetInput()
    {
        var tNameValue = document.getElementById("Name").value;
        var tValue = document.getElementById("Number").value;
        var tArray = document.getElementById('LongText').value.split('\n');
    }
    Check( tArray, tNameValue, tValue )
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < tArray.length; i++ )
        {
        if( i === tNameVaue )
        {
            document.getElementById( 'tOutPut' ).innerText = "Name Match" <br />;
        }
        if( i === tValue )
        {
            document.getElementById( 'tOutPut' ).innerText = "Match" <br />;
        }
        }
    }
```

*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript has many things wrong. Here is the HTML and the Javascript. The logic must be improved but the code is working.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <form>
      <input type="text" id="Name" placeholder="Name" style="width:100%"><br /><br />
      <input type="text" id="Number" placeholder="Number" style="width:100%"><br /><br />
      <input type="text" id="Next" placeholder="Something Else" style="width:100%"><br /><br />
      <input type="text" id="WhatEver" placeholder="Something Else" style="width:100%"><br /><br />
     </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">

      <textarea id="LongText" placeholder="Enter Info" style="width:100%; height:250px">  
      </textarea> <br />

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="tSubmit" value="Submit" onclick="ExecuteAll();">
  </div>


    <div class="col-md-12">
     <h1>Output</h1>
        <div id="tOutPut" style="color:red;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the Javascript:

```
var tNameValue;
var tValue;
var tArray;

function ExecuteAll()
{
    GetInput();
    Check();
}

function GetInput()
{
    tNameValue = document.getElementById("Name").value;
    tValue = document.getElementById("Number").value;
    tArray = document.getElementById('LongText').value.split('\n');
}

function Check()
{
    if (tArray != null) {
        for(var i = 0; i < tArray.length; i++ )
        {

        if( i == tNameValue )
        {
            document.getElementById( 'tOutPut' ).innerText = "Name Match <br />";
        }

        if( i == tValue )
        {
            document.getElementById( 'tOutPut' ).innerText = "Match <br />";
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I will tell you what I did to fix the bugs:

1. Added function keyword to the javascript functions.
2. Put the variables as global so they can be used for the whole code.
3. Verified whether tArray is not null.
4. Fixed variable names.

Here is the Fiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/3U6mE/6/

I hope it helps you get started.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have been working on this since I posted - your tips will definitely help.

Comment: I am really glad I could help. I nice way to say thank you is to up vote the answer and mark it as correct by clicking in the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer. Cheers